# How do I know if a TFont Name is truly supported?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl

When I set the `TFont` `Name` property of a `TRichEdit` control to "Courier" the font changes to Courier.

```
Edit->Font->Name  = "Courier";
```

What if I want to use a font of which I'm not really sure it is supported on the system (e.g. on an older OS) ?
As far as I can tell at the moment, if I assign an 'unknown' Name to the TFont property, the actual font doesn't change, the system takes care of it and sticks with the previous font, but how can I programmatically check this ?

I'd like to know if the font truly changed (because the font is available / installed) ?

Or do I need to query Screen->Fonts to find out if the Name is in the list ?

FYI: Using Borland C++ Builder (2009), but relevant to Delphi as well I'm sure.

Comment: Simple: Get a list of installed fonts, and check if your font is on that list. Sounds like you already have that solution.

Comment: (untested) After assigning the new `Font` settings, query the actual assigned font using `HFONT hFont = (HFONT) SendMessage(Edit->Handle, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0); LOGFONT fnt = {0}; ::GetObject(hFont, sizeof(LOGFONT), &fnt);` and see if `fnt` contains what you are expecting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[TScreen::Fonts](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TScreen_Fonts.html) represents a `TStrings` list that contains the names of the fonts installed in the system (the actual names and not the file names).

Use its [`IndexOf()`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TStringList_IndexOf.html) method to test if your font exists:

```cpp
if (Screen->Fonts->IndexOf("Courier") != -1)
{
    ShowMessage("Font installed");
}
```